# How to optimally utilise 2.4GHz & 5GHz bands?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, dual-band

I have a dual band router which transmits two WiFi signals: one at frequency 2.4GHz and the other at frequency 5GHz.

I’ve read that, in general, the 5GHz band is quicker when at close range to the router with no obstructions to the signal, and the 2.4GHz band provides more coverage and is thus better at further ranges.

Now, I have many devices in my house. I have a total of four iPhones, 3 laptops, XboX and a TV.

Now, should I connect some of these devices to the 5GHz band and others to the 2.4GHz band? Or would it just be better to connect them all to the 5GHz band (as they are all fairly close to the router)?

I have no idea how it works to be honest, I just intuitively think that if all devices were connected to the same band then it would get congested, so the speed would decrease, so maybe it’s better to connect, say, the iPhones to the 2.4GHz and the streaming devices to the 5GHz one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I split devices between 2.4GHz and a 5GHz for a dual-band Wi-Fi AP?](https://superuser.com/questions/1238774/should-i-split-devices-between-2-4ghz-and-a-5ghz-for-a-dual-band-wi-fi-ap)

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't tell us the make and model of your router, it's safe to note there are exactly [three 2.4GHz channels](https://www.howtogeek.com/197268/how-to-find-the-best-wi-fi-channel-for-your-router-on-any-operating-system/)  which don't overlap each other. There are [48 such 5GHz channels stateside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)) and b[onding multiple channels together](http://www.emperorwifi.com/2016/04/channel-bonding-in-wi-fi.html) can yield greater bandwidth still.  You can also use [Thanksgiving-grade aluminum foil](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/aluminum-foil-wi-fi-extension,news-26097.html) near the router as a reflector to direct the signal somewhat, to shape the signal to where it needs to go.