# Are both networks on a dual band router still connected if they have different names?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dual-band

I have a dual band router and I have over 30 devices connected to it. Will the 2.4Ghz and the 5Ghz networks still be able to communicate with each other if the network names are different, or do you have have to name them both the same?

I use many home automation devices, so everything has to be on the same network, so I gave both bands the same network name and password. Is this necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to keep different SSIDs for 2.4GHz and 5GHz wireless networks?](https://superuser.com/questions/362366/does-it-make-sense-to-keep-different-ssids-for-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wireless-networks)

Comment: This question is related, but I don't think the other question covers the particular information this user is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The names of the networks *do not affect whether or not they can communicate with each other*. Many routers have an option of intentionally preventing users on one network (usually a "guest" network) from seeing devices on another, or from seeing other devices on that particular network. However this is generally an option you would need to enable intentionally.

Assuming your routers manufacturer didn't do something abnormal, it should not matter whether or not the two networks have the same name. There are [other considerations](https://superuser.com/questions/362366/does-it-make-sense-to-keep-different-ssids-for-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wireless-networks) you may want to think about with network names, but for this particular question, it's not important.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will have to change it so that I can make sure the more speed needing devices can have the 5Ghz channel. If you feel like it, I would like to hear about the 'other considerations" you mentioned. If not, thanks anyway.

Comment: This question has more details: https://superuser.com/questions/362366/does-it-make-sense-to-keep-different-ssids-for-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wireless-networks